# Hi! I am trying to create a button that will change the css grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create a button that will change the css grid layout. I have a class called container with my grid information.

I want to change the grid with a button press either with html and css or with using js.

Is there to similar way like a hover, have a on click and change the css for that click.

Comment: Yes there likely is a way. What ways have you tried so far? Please may you share those?

Comment: I have tried to create a html button with a class "mybtn. 
I then in js, tried to register a click. but I am not sure how to change css with js and reference a grid. 

I was able to change style text color but thats about it. 
I am very new to all this and I am trying to wrap my mind around the onclick as Ive seen multiple way to click a object on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it for only the duration of the click, then you should try something like this (css):

```css
#myElement:active{
     /*Code Here*/
}
```

If you want it to stay that way after the click, then I would use js. Example:

HTML

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

and js

```js
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('myElement').style.gridTemplateColumns = "auto auto auto"
}
```

## Working Example

```js
function changeGrid(){
  document.getElementById("grid").style.gridTemplateColumns = "auto auto auto"
}
```

```css
#grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeGrid()">Change Grid</button>

<div id="grid">
<div>
hi
</div>
<div>
hello
</div>
<div>
yello
</div>
<div>
hey
</div>
<div>
wassup
</div>
<div>
yo
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way for this to work by class name instead of id? Also I am getting this error : Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function

Comment: yes, you could try `document.querySelectorAll('.container')`, or `document.getElementsByClassname()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Somebody, feel free to improve upon this js is not my *expertise*

Comment: also, @ighc, `document.getElementsById` is *not* a function, but `document.getElementById` is. Singular for elements, not plural

Comment: and dont forget you can also add an id to a element that has a class if there is only one of them

Comment: thanks! I was able to get that working. IS this also a way to change the grid template areas?

Comment: what do you mean? you can change anything by using the format: `document.getElementById('<elementid>').style.<styleaspect> = "code here"`

Comment: @ighc yes. Define a different grid using a different class or id

Comment: @ighc no problem!